# align text with image in title bar on dialog box

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

There is any way to customize with css the "your title" in this Fiddle, for example, put it aligned with the image?
http://jsfiddle.net/saikotju/F9uR3/3/

```
<span class="dialog">English</span>

<div id="dialog" class="dialogBox" title="LessonSelected"></div>

$(function() {

    $('#dialog').dialog({
        resizable:false,
        autoOpen: false,
        title:'<img src="http://weeklyprobateleads.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/download-icon-probate-leads.png" /> Your Title',
        buttons: {
            "Enrol": function(){
                $(this).dialog('close');
                choice(true);
            },
            "Cancel Enrol": function(){
                $(this).dialog('close');
                choice(false);
            }
        }
    });

    $( ".dialog" ).click(function(){        
        $('#dialog').dialog("open");
    });
});


.ui-dialog-title {
    color: white;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
.ui-dialog-title img {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/F9uR3/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
$(function() {
    
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            resizable:false,
            autoOpen: false,
            title:'<img src="http://weeklyprobateleads.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/download-icon-probate-leads.png" /> Your Title',
            buttons: {
                "Enrol": function()
                {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    choice(true);
                },
                "Cancel Enrol": function()
                {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    choice(false);
                }
            }
        });
        
    $( ".dialog" ).click(function(){        
        $('#dialog').dialog("open");
    });
  });
```

```css
.ui-dialog-content div {
    background: url(https://www.google.com/logos/2014/worldcup14/opening/cta.png) no-     repeat  !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span class="dialog">English</span>
    </td>  
    <td>
      <div id="dialog" class="dialogBox" title="LessonSelected">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/2014/worldcup14/opening/cta.png" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```